# I am getting garbage values while running this code in Xcode using objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
- (IBAction)btndlr:(id)sender
{
    NSString *str =txtdata.text;
    lblfinal.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/60",(int)str];

}
```

After running this code without any errors i get garbage value as output in the label.any guidance will be appreciated.thank you.

Comment: Of course you get garbage. What do you expect if you cast a pointer to an int.

Comment: It would be very helpful to provide a) an example of the current output and b) what you consider the proper result.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe the result was as expected and i cant attach any screenshots brother. Bcoz i dnt have 10 reputation thats why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the NSString method `intValue` to make it work, try this:

```
- (IBAction)btndlr:(id)sender
{
    NSString *str = txtdata.text;
    lblfinal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/60",[str intValue]];
}
```

**EDIT:**
If you want to perform the calculation before writing it out, you should change the last line to:

```
lblfinal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[str intValue]/60];
```

And by the way, if you use division you might want a decimal number as output, then you can write:

```
lblfinal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[str floatValue]/60];
```

Hope it helped!

Comment: sir i get the output like value i type/60. i.e. if i type 60 then it shows 60/60 instead of 1. any solutions?

Comment: I've updated my answer, please mark any of the answers as 'accepted' or/and 'useful' instead of just write 'I'm done', thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do computations inside format strings. You have to convert the string to an integer with e.g. the [intValue property](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSString/intValue), and perform the computation outside:

```
- (IBAction)btndlr:(id)sender
{
    NSString *str = txtdata.text;
    lblfinal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", str.intValue / 60];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one

```
- (IBAction)btndlr:(id)sender
{
  NSString *str = txtdata.text;
  lblfinal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[str intValue]/60];

}
```